# Woocommerce Display Featured and Hidden Products above Shop & Category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i need to display featured products above the loop on the shop & category page. I am able to do that, but I also need to hide these products in the default loop.
I wanted to solve this with product visibility settings, but the products are always shown or hidden in both loops.

Ideally, I would like to set the products as featured and hidden, and set my custom loop to ignore visibility settings. I just cant to figure this out.

I'm currently using this code:

```
function featured_products_beforeloop() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 12,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'field'    => 'name',
                'terms'    => 'featured',
            ),
        ),
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
    <ul class="products columns-<?php echo esc_attr( wc_get_loop_prop( 'columns' ) ); ?>">
        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : 
        global $product; ?>
            <li <?php wc_product_class( '', $product ); ?>>  
            <?php  if ( has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID ) ) 
                echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog' ); 
            else 
                echo '<img src="' . woocommerce_placeholder_img_src() . '" alt="' . $product->get_title() . '" class="attachment-shop_catalog size-shop_catalog wp-post-image" width="300px" height="300px" />'; ?>
            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

            <?php if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) : ?>
            <span class="price"><?php echo $price_html; ?></span>
            <?php endif;
            woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $loop->post, $product ); ?>    
        </li>
        <?php 
    endwhile; ?>
</ul> <?php
    wp_reset_postdata();    
} 

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'featured_products_beforeloop', 10 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 12,

    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => 'featured',
        ),
        // allow both hidden and not hidden featured items
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
                'field'    => 'name',
                'terms'    => 'hidden',
                'operator' => 'NOT IN',
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
                'field'    => 'name',
                'terms'    => 'hidden',
                'operator' => '=',
            ),
        )
    ),
);
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, i will try that. i wanted to solve it without changing the standard woocommerce loop. is there no function to ignore visible settings in custom product loops?

Comment: Updated to not modify the default query and allow both hidden and not hidden items as long as they are i the featured cat via the custom query

Comment: thank you for the help. your code did not initially work for me, but then I realized the theme I was using had not been set as woocommerce supported (add_theme_support('woocommerce');). after I set that, it started to work immediately. i could actually solve it with many tries before had I realize that sooner.